# Who can I turn to to have a newspaper article removed from the internet?

Tags: defamation, harassment

I'm trying to get some information removed from the internet. It was  an article which was published by a news publication called The Poughkeepsie Journal, which is located in a town called Poughkeepsie New York. They published a name in an article back in 2011 talking about a list of people set to graduate from a high school that year. I never attended the graduation ceremony because I was the victim of bullying, abuse and harassment by several teachers I had as a result of my disability, and being that I wasn't sure I'd graduate I instead opted to pick up my diploma. Although this article was published some years ago, at times it comes back to haunt me, as at the time the article was published it was under a name I no longer use. I did not give consent for that name to be published, and since the publishing of that article I had experienced harassment and bullying. Consequently, I moved away shortly afterwards and changed my name. I had contacted the Poughkeepsie Journal and asked very politely to remove that name from that article and stated my case in a clear, kind and professional manner. The editor, however, was very rude and quite egotistical about the whole ordeal. It ended with him telling me to contact the school district responsible for sending that information to the Poughkeepsie Journal. Upon contacting the school district, they told me there was nothing they could do at this point and that it didn't matter if I'd given consent or not, as they send photos to the newspaper and those photos contain names of those who either graduated or were set to graduate, and that name is in the article with all the others. Is there anyone who could help me find a pro bono attorney to get that info removed from the internet? The article no longer appears on the original website of the poughkeepsie journal, instead it appears as an archived version on the website newspapers.com. That archived link is what is making the rounds on all the search engines and I'm trying to remove that link. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

If a newspaper publishes an article that is actually defamatory (i.e. publishes false statements that cause you quantifiable harm), and you successfully sue the publisher, you might get a court order requiring them to retract the statements or remove them from their web page. An archive like newspapers.com isn't making false statements, it is making true statements about what the Poughkeepsie Journal published. At any rate, you name is not defamatory, it is (or was) a fact.